# aio download_blob works once but not twice when run with asyncio.run

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, aiohttp, azure-sdk-python

The code aio download_blob of the azure blob works once but not twice when run with asyncio.run, this looks like a bug related to iohttp, but could not figure out how to solve it. (Windows)

The code i have is almost a copy from their original example at:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples/blob_samples_hello_world_async.py

```
from azure.storage.blob.aio import ContainerClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()

async def test(conn_client):
    async with conn_client as client_conn:
        stream = await client_conn.download_blob(my_path)
        data = await stream.readall()
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_container_name = "Container name"
    my_client = ContainerClient.from_container_url(container_url=my_container_name, credential=credentials)
    my_path = 'test_path'

    data = asyncio.run(test(my_client)) # works and returns the file from blob storage
    data2 = asyncio.run(test(my_client)) # doesn't work
```

Error Message:

```
DEBUG - asyncio: Using proactor: IocpProactor
...
    await self.open()
  File "C...\Cache\virtualenvs\transformer-wi-nHELc-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\azure\core\pipeline\transport\_aiohttp.py", line 127, in open
    await self.session.__aenter__()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__aenter__'. Did you mean: '__delattr__'?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any idea or work around?

Answer (score 1):

> aio download_blob works once but not twice when run with asyncio.run Any idea or workaround?

The error tells that in the Azure SDK code is trying to enter a session that is `None`. This can happen when the `aiohttp` session is being closed before the second download operation.

You can pass the destination file path in the list and call the function with that list.

Here is my code to download Blob twice from Blob Storage to the local environment.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob.aio import ContainerClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
import asyncio

async def download_blob(conn_client,path,l):
    for i in l:
        with open(i, "wb") as my_blob:
            stream = await conn_client.download_blob(path)
            data = await stream.readall()
            my_blob.write(data)
            my_blob.close()

async def main():
    my_container_url = "https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/test"
    credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
    my_client = ContainerClient.from_container_url(container_url=my_container_url, credential=credentials)
    my_path = 'your blob name'
    l = [r"C:\Users\xx\xxxx\samp.csv",r"C:\Users\xxxxxx\samp1.csv"]
    await download_blob(my_client, my_path,l)
    await my_client.close()
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

The above code executed and downloaded the CSV file twice to my local folder.

**Files:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply!, unfortunatelly this didn't work, as it downloads the blobs sequentially instead of concurrent because the for is inside the async function instead of a asyncio.gather. Second is that i have different asyncio.run(test(my_client)) at different places of the code that can't be merged together, and even if is 5 min later the second call doesn't work.

Comment: but still your answer is useful, do you know how to manage the aiohttp session so azure sdk doesn't close it? or at least reopen it in the second operation?

Comment: Are you OK with creating a client inside  `download_blob` function?

Comment: If i can avoid it, I would prefer not to, but it seems it may be the only work around, is this a known bug? it seems like a pretty bad one.